# How to generate the best curved fit for an unknown set of 2D points in C++

Tags: c++, best-fit-curve

I am trying to get the best fit for an unknown set of 2D points. The points are centered points of rivers, and they don't come in a certain order.
I've tried to use polynomial regression but I don't know what is the best polynomial order for different sets of data.

I've also tried cubic spline, but I don't want a line through all the points I have, I want an approximation of the best fit line through the points.

I would like to get something like this [image] even for lines that have more curves. This example is computed with polynomial regression, and it works fine.

Is there a way to do some smooth or regression algorithm that can get the best fit line even for a set of points like the following? [image: points]

```
    PolynomialRegression<double> pol;
    static int polynomOrder = <whateverPolynomOrderFitsBetter>;
    double error = 0.005f;
    std::vector<double> coeffs;
    pol.fitIt(x, y, polynomOrder, coeffs);
    // get fitted values
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < points.size(); i++)
    {
        int order = polynomOrder;
        long double yFitted = 0;
        while(order >= 0)
        {
            yFitted += (coeffs[order] * pow(points[i].x, order) + error);
            order --;
        }
        points[i].y = yFitted;
    }
```

In my implementation with an 35 polynomial order this is all I can get [image: check here to see an example], and also changing the polynomial order with higher values turns into Nan values for the coefficients.

I'm not sure if this is the best approach I can have.

Comment: are you looking for linear regression?

Comment: Nope, non-linear

Comment: what is non-linear? The "linear" in linear regression refers to the resulting system of equations. I understand you want to fit a straight line, and linear regression can do that (and much more)

Comment: I don't want to fit a straight line, that's why linear regression cannot work. I used polynomial regression but it doesn't match any time. Did you see the pictures I've attached?

Comment: ok, I misunderstood. No straight line, though "that's why linear regression cannot work" is not right. Anyhow, you should show what you tried and explain why it didnt work

Comment: Well as I researched until now, linear regression is used for straight lines, but maybe I misunderstood too.

Comment: I tried polynomial regression, as already mentioned and I have to add too high polynomial order so that the curve actually fits the points. (For example : the points from the second link)

Comment: actually cubic polynomial regression is a type of [linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression). As mentioned before, the "linear" in linear regression does not refer to the shape of the curve you want to fit

Comment: sorry for the confusion I added. I only read about cubic polynomial regression now. In any case, your issue seems to be the model and the fitting, not c++ code. Maybe you have more luck here: https://math.stackexchange.com/, though I suppose also there you'll need to show more details on what you already did

Comment: yeah, sure. I can try there too, but right now I'm not sure if I want to continue with polynomial regression, this is why I didn't show any code. I want to see other solutions, because I'm not sure this is the more effective way to do it.

Comment: did you browse existing question? Your question is currently too broad and what is wrong with your code is unclear.

Comment: yes, polynomial regression seamed to be the best at that moment but after using it I got confused, and I don't know if I should continue with it

Comment: Also, I've added details on what I've tried.